# docker run で起動しても localhost にアクセスできない: Switch to inspect mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

Docker上にあるRails環境をAzureでデプロイしたいと考えており、チュートリアルをやっていますが、以下の部分で躓いているので教えていただきたいです。

[カスタム コンテナーを使用してカスタム ソフトウェアを Azure App Service に移行する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux)

#### 行ったこと

1. イメージをビルドする

   ```sh
   docker build --tag appsvc-tutorial-custom-image .
   ```
2. Docker コンテナーをローカルで実行して、ビルドの動作をテストします。

   ```sh
   docker run -p 8000:8000 appsvc-tutorial-custom-image
   ```

この2番でlocalhostにアクセスしているのですが、応答がありません。

私がimageを作成したのはDockerのクイックスタートを参考にしたもので[こちら](https://github.com/jinwatanabe/rails_works/tree/19e15e189d0401ba374a41019e3c7546eb294566)となります。

localhost:3000にアクセスするとYou're on railsとなるだけの環境構築しただけになります。

2番は

```sh
docker run -p 3000:3000 appsvc-tutorial-custom-image
```

と変更しました。(3000番のポートにdocker-compose.ymlで設定しているため)

```
Switch to inspect mode.
```

と返答があり、localhost:3000にアクセスしても**このサイトはアクセスできません**となります。

どのようにすればイメージから、localhost:3000にアクセスできるようになるのでしょうか。
また、imageを作成するのはDockerfileから作るものだからできないのかもしれないとも考えましたが、どうなのでしょうか。

`docker run`を利用してimageから起動する方法を教えてほしいです。

Comment: この `docker run` はどこで実行していて、`localhost:3000` へのアクセスはどこからなさっていますか？　どちらもご自身のローカル環境でしょうか。

Comment: どちらもローカル環境(powershell)で行っています。localhost:3000へのアクセスはGoogle Chromeでアクセスしています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[現在の Dockerfile](https://github.com/jinwatanabe/rails_works/blob/19e15e189d0401ba374a41019e3c7546eb294566/Dockerfile) では CMD が指定されていません。このため指定無しで `docker run` した場合、FROM で指定されている ruby:2.5.3 の CMD である `irb` が起動しています。

`docker-compose up` で起動した場合は [docker-compose.yml で指定したコマンド](https://github.com/jinwatanabe/rails_works/blob/19e15e189d0401ba374a41019e3c7546eb294566/docker-compose.yml#L15)である `rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'` が実行されているため、3000 番ポートで Rails が待ち受けてくれています。一方で今回作った Docker イメージでは単に `docker run` するだけだと `irb` が起動するだけなので Rails が起動していません。

このことを手元で試すには、たとえばコマンド引数で CMD を指定する `docker run -p 3000:3000 appsvc-tutorial-custom-image rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'` を実行すると良いです。この場合は `localhost:3000` で Rails へアクセスできます。ただし DB コンテナが起動しておらず DB へのアクセスに失敗するのでエラー画面が表示されるはずです。

単に `docker run -p 3000:3000` しただけで動くようにしたければ、Dockerfile で CMD を指定すると良いでしょう。

Comment: とてもご丁寧にありがとうございます。CMDについて理解できておらずとても参考になりますした。

Comment: docker runで、dbコンテナも一緒に立ち上げることはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 複数の `docker run` コマンドを組み合わせることで可能です。そして、それと同様のことを 1 つのコマンドでできるようにしているのが docker-compose です。

Comment: docker runでrailsとdbを2つ組み合わせたコマンドを教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: それは今回のご質問とは離れるため、経緯も含めて別の質問としてご投稿いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 別の質問にて質問させていただきました。ありがとうございました。